# В чем разница между data и json у Request

Tags: python, requests

```
await self.post(
            "https://3040.com.ua/taxi-ordering",
            json={"callback-phone": self.formatted_phone})
```

и

```
await self.post(
            "https://3040.com.ua/taxi-ordering",
            data={"callback-phone": self.formatted_phone})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам на свой вопрос, вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стоило скопировать ответ текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не было времени.